# susy - how to make it full width (no gutter)?

Tags: css, layout, susy

I got a problem when I using SUSY build a grid. I set wrapper class following:

```
$susy: (
    math: fluid,
    columns: 12,
    gutters: 0.25,
    gutter-position: split,
);
```

the problem is child element inside wrapper. In case sometime I want to make full columns I try to do this

```
@include span(full);
```

but this is not full, It has gutter gap. and I try another

```
@include span(full no-gutters);
```

this make element no gutter but it still leave gutter width.

how can I make it full (no gutter) ? only for some element.

Thanks
Chalat

Answer (score 11):

Block level elements are full-width by default, you don't need any mixin for that. If you are overriding a previous Susy mixin, you can just use `width: 100%`. Or you can do change this element to use `inside no-gutters` to make Susy output what you want.

```
@include span(full inside no-gutters);
```

That works because inside-gutter handling is the same as `split`, but the element has to span the outer width or columns + gutters.